# Replace Leading and Trailing Spaces Oracle

Tags: regex, oracle

I have a column in database table in Oracle having values with leading and trailing spaces. I would like the leading spaces to be replaced with 'P' and trailing spaces with 'T', **using Inline Query only**.

Comment: Please post some sample data and desired result. Also, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace each leading/training space with an equal number of `P`/`T`s then you can use:

```
SELECT REPLACE( REGEXP_SUBSTR( your_column, '^ +' ), ' ', 'P' )
       || TRIM( BOTH FROM your_column )
       || REPLACE( REGEXP_SUBSTR( your_column, ' +$' ), ' ', 'T' )
FROM   your_table
```

If you want to replace the spaces with a single `P`/`T` then:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
         REGEXP_REPLACE( your_column, '(.*?) +$', '\1T' ),
         '^ +(.*)',
         'P\1'
       )
FROM   your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't specify if the amount of your leading and trailing spaces are all of a constant length, something like this could be used only if they are:

```
select  replace(substr('  hello world  ',1, instr('  hello world  ',' ',1,2) ),' ','P')||
        trim('  hello world  ')||
        replace(substr('  hello world  ', instr('  hello world  ',' ',-1,2), length('  hello world  ') ),' ','T')
from dual;
```

Note that, the number "2" in all of the **instr** functions within the query, would represent the constant number of leading/trailing spaces, so you should change it to suit your need.